# Getting unstable data from the dust sensor

Tags: android, arduino, sensors

I am using the following method to get the data from the dust sensor. However, the data I get from the dust sensor seems not stable at all. It can jump from 400 to 5000 within a very short period. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
static void dsm501a_timeout_handler_array( void* arg )
{
  dsm501a_context_t *_context = arg;
  _context->ratio = (float)_context->all_low_time /sampletime_ms * 100;
  _context->value =1.1*pow((_context->ratio),3)-3.8*pow((_context->ratio),2)+520*(_context->ratio)+0.62;
  _context->all_low_time = 0;
  // dsm501a_log("                 ratio %f  ，_context->value %f \n",_context->ratio,_context->value);
}


_context->all_low_time
_context->value =1.1*pow((_context->ratio),3)-3.8*pow((_context-  >ratio),2)+520*(_context->ratio)+0.62;


pm25val = value * pm25coef *10;  // 10 to transform 0.01 cf to 0.1 ft

251， 74 ， 83 ， 79 ， 88 ， 59 ，59，74，
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get spikes in your measurements you could try to implement a simple low pass filter to remove them. Or just create some kind of average of the last X values to get it more stable.

Comment: is there any algorithm i can refer to?

Comment: For average: you could just add the last 10 or so values to an buffer (array) and then calculate the average.

For lowpass: you could try to find a already existing lowpass filter code for arduino

Comment: If my comment helped you solve your problem please mark it as a answer!